# Usage of promises in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, meteor

I am trying to use the new `promise` library with meteor, but it is very undocumented. What is the appropriate usage of `Promise.async` and `Promise.await` (the main functions they state in the library). Here is what I was trying

```
MyModule._writeCommand = function (command) {
  let observers = []
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this._commands.write(`${command}\r`, 'utf8');
    observers.push(this.connections.find({
      name: 'commands'
      lastMessage: { $regex: /^\:$/ }
    }).observe({ changed: resolve }));
  }).finally(() => {
    return Promise.each(observers, (o) => o.stop());
  });
}

MyModule.myFunction = Promise.async(function (command, message) {
  const promise = this._writeCommand('Execute startup')
    .then(() => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.connections.find({
        name: 'messages',
        'lastMessage.message': { $regex: message }
      }).observe({ changed: resolve });
    }));
  return Promise.await(promise);
});
```

Is this the appropriate way to use the `promise` package?